# retrieving data from json response from an API

Tags: json, api, go, interface, maps

I'm trying to get data from json response by storing it in some structs (Airport + coordinates) but I don't know how to deal with that since I'm not good enough with maps and interfaces. The code is showing no errors but MapofAirports is completely empty here is the code:

```
package main

import (
    //"api/client"
    //"api/client/clienterrors"
    //"api/client/openstreetmap"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "math"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
)

type Coordinates struct {
    Longitude string `json:"lon"`
    Latitude  string `json:"lat"`
}

type Airport struct {
    Co       Coordinates `json:"location"`
    IATACode string      `json:"id"`
    Distance float64     `json:"distance"` // distance to coordinates in kilometer
}

func GetCoordinatesFromURL(url string) (float64, float64) {

    parts := strings.Split(url, "=")

    lat0 := strings.Split(parts[2], "&")
    lon0 := strings.Split(parts[3], "&")

    lat1, _ := strconv.ParseFloat(lat0[0], 64)
    lon1, _ := strconv.ParseFloat(lon0[0], 64)

    return lat1, lon1
}

func CalcDistance(lat1 float64, long1 float64, lat2 float64, long2 float64) float64 {

    var latitude1 = lat1 * math.Pi / 180
    var latitude2 = lat2 * math.Pi / 180
    var longitude1 = long1 * math.Pi / 180
    var longitude2 = long2 * math.Pi / 180

    var R = 6371.0
    var d = R * math.Acos(math.Cos(latitude1)*math.Cos(latitude2)*math.Cos(longitude2-longitude1)+math.Sin(latitude1)*math.Sin(latitude2))

    return d
}

func main() {
    var Locations []Airport
    Locations = make([]Airport, 0)

    var url = fmt.Sprintf("https://api.skypicker.com/locations?type=radius&lat=40.730610&lon=-73.935242&radius=250&location_types=airport&limit=3&sort=id&active_only=true")

    UrlLat, UrlLon := GetCoordinatesFromURL(url)

    resp, err := http.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)

    var airportsJsonResponse interface{}

    err = json.Unmarshal(body, &airportsJsonResponse)

    MapofAirports, ok := airportsJsonResponse.([]interface{})

    if ok {
        lenAiroMap := len(MapofAirports)

        locationsMaps := make(map[int]map[string]interface{})

        for i := 0; i < lenAiroMap; i++ {
            locationsMaps[i] = MapofAirports[i].(map[string]interface{})
        }
        var coords Coordinates
        for i := 0; i < lenAiroMap; i++ {
            if longitude, ok0 := locationsMaps[i]["lon"].(string); ok0 {
                if latitude, ok1 := locationsMaps[i]["lat"].(string); ok1 {
                    coords = Coordinates{longitude, latitude}
                }
            }
            code := locationsMaps[i]["id"].(string)

            latFromCoordinates, _ := strconv.ParseFloat(Locations[i].Co.Latitude, 64)
            lonFromCoordinates, _ := strconv.ParseFloat(Locations[i].Co.Longitude, 64)

            dist := CalcDistance(latFromCoordinates, lonFromCoordinates, UrlLat, UrlLon)
            Locations = append(Locations, Airport{
                Co:       coords,
                IATACode: code,
                Distance: dist,
            })
        }
    }
    LocationsJson, err := json.Marshal(Locations)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Cannot encode to JSON ", err)
    }
    fmt.Fprintf(os.Stdout, "%s", LocationsJson)
}
```

[screenshot of json response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJNGd.png)

in the screenshot this is the json response we have, and I'm processing like this:

```
{ locations[],meta,last_refresh,results_retrieved } ==> location : { id , location + distance(calculated with a function) }
```

Comment: If you know the JSON structure upfront, and you're willing to use Go structs, then do not use maps and empty interfaces. https://play.golang.com/p/MG1tX8Zbumu

Comment: I would also recomment going with structs if the data structure is known. You can [convert JSON to Go structs using online tools](https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/).

Comment: @mkopriva thanks for your answer, it's really efficient, but I still have one only problem, if I want to add #Distance float64  `json:"distance"`# to the struct and want to get the value by using CalcDistance() function and lon,lat parameters, what should I do ?

Comment: @herotet you could have `CalcDistance` be a method on the type that has access to the coordinates, whether it be `Location` or `LocationItem` is up to you. If you need the `Distance` to be a field, then you can calculate it after you're done with the unmarshaling by looping over the struct instances into which you've unmarshaled the json, this is very easy. If you want to calculate the distance at the same time as you are unmarshaling, you can have the type, into which you are unmarshaling, implement the `json.Unmarshaler` interface.

Comment: @herotet here's an example of the post-unmarshal-loop https://play.golang.com/p/UTKItnPaXs3

Comment: @mkopriva can you please have a look at my last answer down on the page ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is my last update and while running the program it panics at unmarshaling step

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "math"
    "net/http"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
)

type Coordinates struct {
    Longitude string `json:"lon"`
    Latitude  string `json:"lat"`
}

type Airport struct {
    Co       Coordinates `json:"location"`
    IATACode string      `json:"id"`
    Distance float64     `json:"distance"` // distance to coordinates in kilometer
}

type Response struct {
    Locations []Airport `json:"locations"`
    // add all the other fields you care about
}

func GetCoordinatesFromURL(url string) (float64, float64) {

    parts := strings.Split(url, "=")

    lat0 := strings.Split(parts[2], "&")
    lon0 := strings.Split(parts[3], "&")

    lat1, _ := strconv.ParseFloat(lat0[0], 64)
    lon1, _ := strconv.ParseFloat(lon0[0], 64)

    return lat1, lon1
}

func CalcDistance(lat1 float64, long1 float64, lat2 float64, long2 float64) float64 {

    var latitude1 = lat1 * math.Pi / 180
    var latitude2 = lat2 * math.Pi / 180
    var longitude1 = long1 * math.Pi / 180
    var longitude2 = long2 * math.Pi / 180

    var R = 6371.0
    var d = R * math.Acos(math.Cos(latitude1)*math.Cos(latitude2)*math.Cos(longitude2-longitude1)+math.Sin(latitude1)*math.Sin(latitude2))

    return d
}

func main() {


    var url = fmt.Sprintf("https://api.skypicker.com/locations?type=radius&lat=40.730610&lon=-73.935242&radius=250&location_types=airport&limit=3&sort=id&active_only=true")

    UrlLat, UrlLon := GetCoordinatesFromURL(url)

    resp, err := http.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

     data, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    res := &Response{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal(data, res); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(res.Locations)

    for i, item := range res.Locations {
        latt,_ := strconv.ParseFloat(item.Co.Latitude, 64)
        lonn,_ :=strconv.ParseFloat(item.Co.Longitude, 64)
        res.Locations[i].Distance = CalcDistance(latt,lonn , UrlLat, UrlLon)
    }
    fmt.Println("after calculate distance")
    fmt.Println(res.Locations)
}
```

what's wrong with that ?

Comment: goroutine 1 [running]:
main.main()
 C:/Users/herotet/go/src/CT_ProjectV2/main.go:70 +0x536

Comment: and when I debug I get this :
json: cannot unmarshal number into Go struct field Coordinates.locations.location.lat of type string

Comment: Change Lat Lon field types from `string` to `float64`.

Comment: I still have one only question, since it's a group work and others already worked with latitude and longitude as strings , how should i do it i want the same results but with this condition ?

Comment: Do you need it to be `string` in the `Coordinates` type? or do you need it to be `string` in the response json that you're sending back to the client that made the initial request?

Comment: I would like it to be string in coordinates type

Comment: In that case you need to have the `*Coordinates` type implement the `json.Unmarshaler` interface. Something like this: https://play.golang.com/p/_UhF5fx5b9j

Comment: excuse me but I can't see where should i call this function 
and also i don't understand what '(c *Coordinates)' in << func (c *Coordinates) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error>> means

Comment: You don't have to, that's called automatically by `json.Unmarshal` (https://play.golang.com/p/EcibN8HSgVj). And `func (x T) M( ...` is a method declaration (https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_declarations).